# Is there a way to detect a mouse action which is a "isReleased" on a JLabel?

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseevent, jlabel, mouselistener

I'm a beginner at Java, here I'm trying to create a Minesweeper game (I still have to learn a lot, so I'm challenging myself by making this game with JLabel, not JButton or any things that is the same kind, by the way, the code is all by myself :> proudly I can say, haha). Anyway, I'm at the part where I need to detect if a slot contains a bomb, or a number, or none. You know, when playing, if you click on a slot that contains nothing, the game will automatically open all the nearby slot (which also contain nothing). My idea is to use MouseAdapter, so I can use MouseEvent.getSource(), or getButton(). But I'm literally stuck! Can someone figure out what do I need to do? It will be very thankful! (and so for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker)

First, I have to inform that I make two package in the same folder, one is for the display, or UI, and one is all the values that connects to the other one.

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation! So you would mind click the link to see my image)

[PACKAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcluh.png)

This is the "Square" class, which is a JLabel, I want each of the slot inside the game to interact with player's mouse, so I implement the MouseListener here.

```java
package Graphics;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Square extends JLabel implements MouseListener {   
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public int squareWidth = 50, squareLength = 50;
    Color foreGround;
    
    Color grass1 = new Color(170, 215, 80);
    Color grass2 = new Color(165, 210, 75);
    Color dirt1 = new Color(230, 195, 160);
    Color dirt2 = new Color(215, 185, 155);

    public Square(int x, int y, Color fg, Color bg) {
        foreGround = fg;
        this.setForeground(bg);
        this.setFont(new Font("ArcadeClassic", Font.BOLD, 40));
        this.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        this.setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());
        this.setBounds(x, y, squareWidth, squareLength);
        this.setBackground(bg);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        this.setForeground(foreGround);
        if(this.getBackground().getRed() == 170) this.setBackground(dirt1);
        if(this.getBackground().getRed() == 165) this.setBackground(dirt2);
        System.out.println("" + this.getX() + " - "  + this.getY());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    
}
```

This is inside the "GamePanel" class, "extends JPanel", I'm just trying to initialize a 2-D ArrayList with datatype is Square, set the x-coord, y-coord, background color and foreground color for the slot.

```java
package Graphics;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import Logics.Field;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    Color grass1 = new Color(170, 215, 80);
    Color grass2 = new Color(165, 210, 75);
    Color dirt1 = new Color(230, 195, 160);
    Color dirt2 = new Color(215, 185, 155);
    
    int row = 5, col = 5;
    Square square[][] = new Square[row][col];
    Field field = new Field(row, col);
    
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setBackground(new Color(75, 120, 45));     
        field.createBomb(3);
        field.printValue();     
        int x = 20, y = 5;
        int len = 0;
        byte step = 0;      
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                Color temp = null;
                switch(field.getValue(i, j)) {
                    case 1: {
                        temp = Color.blue; break;}
                    case 2: {
                        temp = new Color(75, 120, 45); break;}
                    case 3: {
                        temp = Color.red; break;}
                    case 4: {
                        temp = new Color(125, 30, 165); break;}
                    case 5: {
                        temp = new Color(255, 145, 0); break;}
                    case 6: {
                        temp = new Color(0, 150, 170); break;}}
                if(step == 0) {
                    square[i][j] = new Square(x, y, temp, grass1);
                    step = 1;}
                else {
                    square[i][j] = new Square(x, y, temp, grass2);
                    step = 0;}
                this.add(square[i][j]);
                x += square[i][j].squareWidth;
                len = square[i][j].squareLength;}
            y += len;
            x = 20;}
        this.setSquareText();
        this.setLayout(null);
    }
    
    public void setSquareText() {
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if(field.getValue(i, j) == 0) square[i][j].setText("");
                else if(field.getValue(i, j) == -1) square[i][j].setText("x");
                else square[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(field.getValue(i, j)));
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

If needed, I will capture the Logics package for you guys! (Sorry if the code is hard to watch, I have to shorten it down so that I can capture it!)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: OK cool. So it looks like your square knows when it got clicked on, but it doesn't know what's in the rest of the game panel. The GamePanel does though, so the next step is to create a method in GamePanel that Square can call that says "hey I'm square at i/j and I've been clicked on. Then from game panel run a "Flood Fill" algorithm. You can Google that term if you get stuck on that part.

Comment: @luckydog32 thanku, i will learn about this algorithm and will update my code later as soon as possible, thank u again for ur advise!

Comment: i have complete my code, thank u guys again very muchhh